# Add attachment to a jira issue via jira python (empty file added)

Tags: python, api, jira

I am trying to add an attachment to an existing jira issue using the jira python API.

I'm able to create issues, update them and whatever actions regarding the issues but when I try to add an attachment, I either get a 200 response and an error saying the attchment added is empty (it's actually empty) or an error saying "No space left on device" and I don't think it's about the space here since I am able to manually add the attachment on jira interface.

My code add first informations to a new file and then try to attach it to the issue. Note that the actual file in my code directory is not empty and met my expectation.

```
f = open("matriceFlux.csv","w+")
ligneEntete = ";".join(entete)+"\n"
f.write(ligneEntete)
for valeur in valeurs:
    ligne=";".join(valeur)+"\n"
    f.write(ligne)
f.close() #I didn't close the files object for the first try
fichier=open("matriceFlux.csv", 'rb')
jira.add_attachment(issue=fluxIssue, attachment=fichier)
matriceFlux.close() #I didn't close the files object for the first try
```

The output is

```
raise JIRAError("Added empty attachment via %s method?!: r: 
%s\nattachment: %s" % (method, r, attachment))
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP Added empty attachment via 
MultipartEncoder method?!: r: <Response [200]>
attachment: matriceFlux.csv
```

when I don't close the files object

and this when I do

```
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 500 url: https://rec- 
jira.*******.fr/rest/api/2/issue/GDIOP-15782/attachments
text: No space left on device

    response headers = {'X-AREQUESTID': '562x1107300x1', 'X-ASESSIONID': 
'g9s4x6', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 
'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Security-Policy': 
"frame-ancestors 'self'", 'X-ASEN': 'SEN-2015665', 'X-Seraph- 
LoginReason': 'OK', 'X-AUSERNAME': 'my752lf', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, 
no-store, no-transform', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF- 
8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Thu, 11 Jul 2019 07:22:23 
GMT', 'Connection': 'close'}
    response text = No space left on device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually linked to the space on the jira server....After the dba cleaned it, the file got attached to the issue. Also since I didn't close the file object the first time, my code created another file which was the empty file added.

I hope it helps someone.